# Find the General Solutions of coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this kind of problem?

$\frac{d}{d z} 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}\Omega_1(z)\\\Omega_2(z)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}a(z)&b(z)\\c(z)&d(z)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}\Omega_1(z)\\\Omega_2(z)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]$

I want the form of the general solution.

Like, if a,b,c and d are all constants, I can write down the general solutions of $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ as follows:

$
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}\Omega_1(z)\\\Omega_2(z)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]=A\,v_1\,e^{\lambda_1 z}+B\,v_2\,e^{\lambda_2 z}$

where $v_1$, $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}a(z)&b(z)\\c(z)&d(z)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]$ and $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues of $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}a(z)&b(z)\\c(z)&d(z)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]$.

But now they are not constants.

Actually, they can be function or polynomial of z like: $\sin(z)$ or $z\sin(z)$.. or $\cos(z)-A$, etc.
(A is a constant).

Is it possible to find the general solutions?

Comment: You might be interested in reviewing https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Time_Variant_System_Solutions and https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap11.pdf - just to get you started.

Comment: @Moo Thank you, I start to read it now :)